# Turn "log slow queries" ON

Tags: mysql, ssh, centos, logging, service

I'm trying to log mysql slow queries, but I can't turn it on.

I will explain all my steps:

Open and Edit my.cnf and add the following lines:

```
long_query_time = 5
slow_query_log_file = /myfolder/slowq.log
log_slow_queries = 1                     =>(I have MySQL 5.0.7)
```

Give mysql user permitions to write on the file:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Create the file:

```
touch /myfolder/slowq.log
```

Chmod for this file to 777.

```
service mysqld restart
```

From MySQL Admin Panel I can see that the "log_slow_queries" var is OFF!
Also no logs are created.

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards, Panos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

into my.cnf write this under mysqld then you need to restart the server(mysql) also make sure you can write int the directory where you want to log

```
[mysqld]
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysqld-slow-queries.log
```